# Create fields dynamically in custom form

Tags: ajax, drupal, form-submit

I am building a custom module for Drupal 7. It contains a huge form. I created a jQuery code which modifies the form and adds some new selects, text fields and checkboxes.

When I submit the form I am not able to read data from fields which were added by jQuery.

I downloaded Examples for Developers (http://drupal.org/project/examples). There is one example called Add-more button (ajax_example). It seems that is submits all data, increases a counter, rebuilds whole form with new fields and then rendered form is sent back. Is there any possibility to avoid sending whole form server to client? It is not the fastest solution.

I would like to modify my form using jQuery, submit it, rebuild it and validate it. Each change would not require sending data to server.

Thank you, Martin.

Answer (score 1):

`I submit the form I am not able to read data from fields which were added by jQuery`

Make sure that you add a `name` field to your `inputs` and `select` elements.

The `$_POST['here_is_the_name_which_you_give_to_your_elements']` reads the value of inputed form fields server side.

I decipher that the form will have multiple inputs and selects which are created dynamically. 
To manage that:

Add `[]` after the `value` of the `name` field.
For Eg:

```
 <input type='text' value='' name='my_custom_input[]' id='this_is_not_reqiured_1'>
 <input type='text' value='' name='my_custom_input[]' id='this_is_not_reqiured_2'>
```

You can get the value of all the `<input>` with `name` = `my_custom_input` on the server side in an Array via `POST` or `GET`.

Note: `ID` is not needed but you can use and maintain a counter if you need those DOM elements Manipulated.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is not so simple in Drupal.